# How to fix Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm getting this error although my imports are fine.

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. 
>   Check the render method of 'BottomNavigation'.

My code looks like this:

**index.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  Button,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  Component,
} from 'react-native';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
import Jogadores from '../jogadores';
import Lista from '../jogadores/lista';



function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.home}>    
      <ScrollView scrollEventThrottle={16}>
        <View>
          <Text style={styles.texto}>Principais Vídeos</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.slider}>
          <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
            <Lista
              imageUri={require('../../images/ronald-juv.jpg')}
              name="Cristiano Ronaldo"/>
              <Lista
              imageUri={require('../../images/messi-footer.jpg')}
              name="Lionel Messi"/>
              <Lista
              imageUri={require('../../images/neymar.jpg')}
              name="Neymar"/>
              <Lista
              imageUri={require('../../images/salah.jpg')}
              name="Mohamed Salah"/>
              <Lista
              imageUri={require('../../images/mbappe.jpg')}
              name="Kylian Mbappé"/>
              <Lista
              imageUri={require('../../images/alisson.jpg')}
              name="Alisson"/>
              <Lista
              imageUri={require('../../images/bruyne.jpg')}
              name="Kevin De Bruyne"/>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

export default function Home({navigation}) {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
     activeColor="#F00"
      barStyle={{backgroundColor: '#272727'}}>
      <Tab.Screen
       name="Home"
        component={HomeScreen}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel:'Home',
          tabBarIcon:({color,size}) =>(
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="soccer" color={'#fff'} size={15} />
          )
        }} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Jogadores" component={Jogadores} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={HomeScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: What is ‘BottomNavigation’ ?

Answer (score 0):

This usually means one of your imports isn’t right. I’d recommend setting a breakpoint in your render method and inspecting each import, looking for one that doesn’t look right. (Either that or `console.log` each imported component and look for it there.